# wcat for load testing asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, load-testing, stress-testing, wcat

I am new to load testing and i want to load test my asp.net web site. After doing some investigation I came across this tool wcat by Microsoft for load testing. To me it seems to be a stress tool for putting load on one or multiple pages, more like testing the IIS and not the application itself. But what if i want to simulate a scenario, for example i have a wizard in my website that has multiple steps. The user is able to follow 4-5 steps to create a record.
Is Wcat the right tool to test my asp.net website for the wizard above? If yes, can i be pointed to some guide that does the same?

Answer (score 0):

Wcat can load test web applications and navigation scenarios. However, it does not have a recorder, so you need to create your own script reflecting the navigation steps.

Fortunately, you can use Fiddler as a recorder and then export captured sessions as Wcat script as described in [this blog](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/05/11/using-the-wcat-fiddler-extension-for-web-server-performance-tests.aspx).  Until recently, Fiddler's WCAT exporter did not support POST requests but it may have been added by now [as described here](http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/browse_thread/thread/34744699b9dd0258/555074e3ad3cfbdf).

Answer (score 0):

This is the old question. Since answer has not marked yet, here is my thought.  WCAT is web application stress or load test tool. It would send send concurrent users requests to web server.

The scenario you talked about is testing a functionality of wizard. Though there are various tools available to test this, I would suggest that [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) which could test the exact scenario you are expecting. This test tool mainly used for test an application using browser as user do. Steps of the wizard could be recorded and replayed and assertion would make sure the test results are expected.